# Compile time map "search" in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have next simplified callbacks map. Please excuse me if the code contains some erros, but it's a very simplified version of actual code to be able to reproduce it here.

```
struct CallbacksMap
{
    template<typename T, typename U>
    void Add(T* obj, void (T::*objCallback)(const U&))
    {
        CallbackBaseType* c = new CallbackType<T, U>(obj, objCallback);
        _callbacks[std::type_index(typeid(U))].push_back(std::unique_ptr<CallbackBaseType>(c));
    }

    template<typename T>
    void Remove(T* obj){...}

    template<typename T>
    void Call(const T& param)
    {
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>& callbacks = _callbacks[std::type_index(typeid(T))];
        for(auto callback = callbacks.begin(); callback != callbacks.end(); ++callback)
        {
            (*callback)->Call(&param);
        }
    }

    std::map<std::type_index, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<CallbackBaseType>>> _callbacks;
};
```

In this sample I can call all the functions with same parameter type by calling `Call(param)` member function. My problem is that the search in `_callbacks` is done at run time even if the key is known at compile time.

I can't make the callbacks list static local to a template function based on type_index of the type because I need to keep track of all the objects for the `Remove(T* obj)` function.

Do you know how can I make the internal structure to be able to avoid this runtime overhead?

Comment: If the map is not known at compile-time, then how can the search be?

Comment: This is why I put "search" in the title, because it's not a real search... I think this is lack of inspiration(the title is really bad) I just need a way to get the list of callbacks for a type and also to get a list of all registered callbacks to be able to remove dead ones.

Comment: You could accomplish it with MPL, but your callbacks should not be T's member functions. They should be some types.

Comment: And also strange thing in your code is that callback is T's member function, receiving U, but when calling you pass only one instance to call...

Comment: @kassak I want to call all Ts that have a member function with U type as parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the `CallbacksMap` a template:

```
template<typename T>
struct CallbacksMap
{
    template<typename U>
    static void Add(T* obj, void (T::*objCallback)(const U&))
    {
        CallbackBaseType* c = new CallbackType<T, U>(obj, objCallback);
        auto& callbacks = callbacks();
        callbacks.push_back(std::unique_ptr<CallbackBaseType>(c));
    }

    static void Remove(T* obj){...}

    static void Call(const T& param)
    {
        auto& callbacks = callbacks();
        for(auto callback = callbacks.begin(); callback != callbacks.end(); ++callback)
        {
            (*callback)->Call(&param);
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<CallbackBaseType>& callbacks()
    {
        static std::vector<std::unique_ptr<CallbackBaseType> _callbacks;
        return _callbacks;
    }
};
```

In this way the type lookup is done by the compiler. Of course this implies you have to call differently the callback by using something like:

```
template <typename T>
void CallCallbacks(const T& param)
{
    CallbacksMap<T>(param);
}

CallCallbacks(param);
```